# How to condition route model bindings by actions in RouteServiceProvider

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have an application which needs to accomplish this in RouteServiceProvider.php:

```
//in \App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    //

    parent::boot($router);

    //somehow can get the current action

    $action = $router->getCurrentAction();

    if($action == 'edit'){  
        $router->model('articles','App\Article');       
    } else{
        $router->bind('articles', function($id){
            return Article::published()->findOrFail($id);
        });
    }  
}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController');
```

Here is my Controller:

```
public function show(Article $article){

    return view('articles.show',compact('article'));
}

public function edit(Article $article){

    return view('articles.edit',compact(['article','tags']));

}
```

The reason I want to do it because I want `show` action only shows published articles while `edit` action can change both published and unpublished articles.

if there is any better solution, please teach me. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make a middleware, that will work only for 'published' routes, where you will check if your Article is published?

Comment: middleware used to filter requests. but in my case, I would like to filter model binding based on given actions. In addition, in my controller, actions already is bound to model `edit(Article $articles){}`

Comment: Your binding is actually a request parameter. Only in your situation parameter is not an integer ID, but a resolved model. Moreover you can find this binding in your route object. So in my opinion filter your model in the middleware an optimal decision.

Answer (score 0):

Based in your route, I assume that you have the following paths:

- example.com/edit
- example.com/3 *- article ID*

So, you could use a pattern to bind the article:

public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

```
// bind 
$router->bind('article', function($id){
    return Article::published()->findOrFail($id);
});

// id pattern
 $router->pattern('id', '[0-9]+');
```

}

Now, just declare the respective routes:

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticlesController@showAll');
Route::get('{id}', 'ArticlesController@edit');
```

Finally, your controller could looks like this:

```
class ArticlesController{

    public funcion showAll(){
        // show a list of articles
    }

    public function edit(Article $article){
        // selected article
    }
}
```

Try to get the best of Laravel using class injection  and keeping cleaning code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your solution is different from what you want. I would like to have decisions to get Article object based on actions. For example, `show(Article $articles)` and `edit(Article $articles)`  will have different resultset  even the parameter `{articles}` has the same value.

Comment: @why, Let me know the two urls that you are using to differ actions

Comment: my route using resource method `Route::resource('articles', 'ArticlesController')` .

Comment: why are you using a resource? are you working with an API?

Comment: because I have an Article store which need a RESTful controller. there are more actions such as `index`,`store`,`create`. But I try to simplify my question.